# Haskell length list + factorial

Tags: haskell, integer-overflow

I'm very new to Haskell. I've been trying to implement `n_choose_r` but for some reason my factorial function is returning strange values.

Main.hs

```
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = n * factorial (n-1)

subsets k list = factorial n where
    n = length list
```

some different cases

```
> subsets 3 [1..4]
24 // correct value
> factorial 60
8320987112741390144276341183223364380754172606361245952449277696409600000000000000
> subsets 3 [1..60]
-8718968878589280256 // wrong value
> subsets 3 [1..100]
0 // wrong value
```

It seems the numbers get wonkier the longer the list. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `factorial` function is polymorphic: it has type `(Eq p, Num p) => p -> p`. When you just call it like `factorial 60`, `p` gets instantiated as `Integer` (this choice is called "type defaulting"), which is arbitrary-precision and has no upper bound. However, `length` is not polymorphic in its output: it always returns an `Int`. Haskell won't automatically convert between numeric types for you, so when you call `factorial` with the result of `length`, it uses `Int` too, which does have an upper bound, which in your case appears to be `9223372036854775807` (which you can verify by doing `maxBound :: Int`). To work around this problem, you can either convert from `Int` to `Integer` yourself:

```
subsets k list = factorial (toInteger n) where
    n = length list
```

or use `genericLength`, which is the same as `length` except for being polymorphic in its output type:

```
import Data.List

subsets k list = factorial n where
    n = genericLength list
```

Note that if you use the latter option, you need to be careful not to do anything else that would force use of `Int` instead of defaulting to `Integer`.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Thanks so much! I didn't realize there was a difference between Int and Integer. Just looked it up and found the difference. You're a lifesaver 